# asp.Net Core one-to-many relationship UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I am using Entity Framework Core and created one-to-many relationship between 2 tables:

```
public class Fgf
  {
     public int FgfID { get; set; }

    public string FGFName { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

}


 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
...
}
```

In this case EFCore is adding automatically FgfID column in ApplicationUser, but I cannot access it in the controller.

I am trying to add the FgfID in the ApplicationUser

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
...

   public int FgfID { get; set; }
   public Fgf Fgf { get; set; }
}
```

I have a form, where I create an FGF and assign to him a user with a selectlist. I am using a simple form with POST action. I am not using model for the form as I have another form on this Razor Page.

In the controller I have:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> NewFgf(string FGFName, string ApplicationUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var fgf = new Fgf
            {
                FGFName = FGFName,                    
            };

            var usertoupdate = await _context.Users
                .Where(c=> c.Id == ApplicationUser)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            usertoupdate.FgfID = fgf.FgfID;
            
            _context.Users.Update(usertoupdate);
            _context.Add(fgf);             
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));              
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The error I get is:

SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUsers_Fgf_FgfID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-StreamPixelVer2-3E2C2112-15B8-48A4-8619-4773C5ADBFBD", table "dbo.Fgf", column 'FgfID'.
The statement has been terminated.

What am I doing wrong? What is the best practice to save the data to the DB with Many-To-One, One-To-Many relationship with the Asp.net Core?

Comment: add `fgf` before update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have fgf.FgfID, try  this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;

.....
....

var usertoupdate = await _context.Set<ApplicationUser>()
                .Where(c=> c.Id == applicationUser.Id)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

      var fgf = new Fgf
            {
                FGFName = FGFName,                    
            };  
        

  fgf.ApplicationUsers = new ObservableCollectionListSource<ApplicationUser>();
  fgf.ApplicationUsers.Add(usertoupdate);  
    _context.Set<Fgf>().Add(fgf);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: ObservableCollectionListSource - The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollectionListSource<>' could not be found.

Comment: Sorry for typo. I just updated the answer

Comment: Try to add  using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking namespace

Comment: How can I construct a Query to select all the users, who have not been assigned an fgf. As I still cannot access the FgfID column in the ApplicationUsers Entity, my query shows an error. Here is the query: `  return Json(_context.Users
                .Select(u => new { UserId = u.Id, LastName = u.LastName, FirstName = u.FirstName, UserEmail = u.Email})
                .OrderBy(o => o.UserEmail)
                .Where( f => f.FgfID==null 
                )
                .ToList()); `

Comment: try _context.Set<ApplicationUser>().Where( u => u.FgfID==null ).Select(u => new { UserId = u.Id, LastName = u.LastName, FirstName = u.FirstName, UserEmail = u.Email}).OrderBy(o => o.UserEmail).ToArray();  - @Aram

Comment: Only pls change in the class ApplicationUser public int FgfID { get; set; } - to public int? FgfID { get; set; }. Or maybe it will work (but I am not sure)  .Where( u => u.FgfID==0 ). - @Aram

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. I will try it.  But the problem is that I do not see FgfID in the class ApplicationUser to change it to nullable . It is added automatically by the EF core.  When I add it manually in the class I am getting an error of a FK constraint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227106/discussion-between-aram-and-sergey).